# Disconnecting Monitor From Raspberry Pi while Running Script

Tags: c, linux, raspberry-pi

I currently have a C script on the Pi that controls a spectrometer (through a USB input) and a servo motor through the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi.  The program requires a few user inputs, so I need a monitor connected to start the program.  However, I may be needing to run this script for a while, so I need to unplug my laptop once the script is running.  Right now, when I unplug my laptop, the script stops running, but it is fine to run as long as I ask it to when I keep the laptop hooked up.  Any advice on how to remotely run a script that still requires a user input in the terminal window?

Answer (score 1):

You could get the IP address of the Pi using `ifconfig` and remotely log into it from a different computer and run the script remotely

Answer (score 1):

Use utilities like `screen` or `tmux`. They will be available through your package manager.